# Data insertion in Firebase realtime database goes infinite

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to insert data in firebase after checking matching few values and inserting my data into those objects. but it works well before data insertion as data insertion code executes main UI thread halts and infinite insertions in firebase real-time database starts.

here is the code:

```
final Schedule schedule = new Schedule(latestCalendar.getTimeInMillis(),String.valueOf(hourOfDay)+":"+String.valueOf(minute)+" - "+String.valueOf(hourOfDayEnd)+":"+String.valueOf(minuteEnd));
final HashMap<String, Object> teamMap = (HashMap<String, Object>) new ObjectMapper().convertValue(schedule, Map.class);
AppBaseActivity.firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            final UserModel user = postSnapshot.getValue(UserModel.class);
            AppBaseActivity.firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Users").child(user.getUid()).child("Teams").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        final Team myTeam = postSnapshot.getValue(Team.class);
                        if (teamID.equals(myTeam.getTid())) {
                            final String tid = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-", "").toUpperCase();
                            // It goes infinite on this code
                            AppBaseActivity.firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Users").child(user.getUid()).child("Teams").child(myTeam.getTid()).child("Schedule").child(tid).setValue(teamMap);
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                    // Failed to read value
                    Toast.makeText(ScheduleTeam.this, getString(R.string.cancel), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        // Failed to read value
        Toast.makeText(ScheduleTeam.this,getString(R.string.cancel),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: You're attaching two listeners to data, and then modify the data inside those listeners. That will then in turn trigger the listener again, which then modifies the data again. That's indeed an infinite loop. What is the code trying to accomplish?

Comment: Filtering data and then inserting values based on those filtered values.

Comment: Can you suggest me some alternate?

Comment: Typically you should filter the data by using a query: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data. Ideally you'll want to write the query in such a way that the modification doesn't cause another trigger for that data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks quite overcomplicated. Keep in mind that attaching a listener to `/Users` will read *all* users into your Android app. If you're only looking for one specific user, loading all of them is wasting a lot of bandwidth and processing power of your Android device. You're much better off loading only the user you need, by using a query:

```
DatabaseReference users =
AppBaseActivity.firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Users");
Query userQuery = users.orderByChild("tid").equalTo(teamID);
userQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            final UserModel user = postSnapshot.getValue(UserModel.class);
            for (DataSnapshot teamSnapshot: postSnapshot.child("Teams")
                final Team myTeam = teamSnapshot.getValue(Team.class);
                if (teamID.equals(myTeam.getTid())) {
                    final String tid = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-", "").toUpperCase();
                    teamSnapshot.getRef().child("Schedule").child(tid).setValue(teamMap);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        Toast.makeText(ScheduleTeam.this,getString(R.string.cancel),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Some of the changes:

1. This code only reads the user(s) with `tid` equal to the value of `teamID`.
2. This code reads the teams of that user straight from the data snapshot it already loaded, instead of attaching another listener.
3. This code builds the path to the `Schedule` from the snapshot, instead of reconstructing it from the root.

As far as I can see this code does the same as yours. But there was a bit much going on there, so there may be minor mistakes. In general I'd recommend trying to understand the 3 changes I described above, since they're likely to be more helpful than copy/paste code.

Comment: Yeah, it looks similar to my code but making few changes will make it work like a charm for mine need.
Thanks!